# How to count unique words in a text file?

Tags: java

I have implemented code to count number of:
- chars
- words
- lines
- bytes 
in text file. 
But how to count dictionary size: number of different words used in this file?
Also, how to implement iterator which can iterate over only letters? (Ignore whitespaces)

```
public class wc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //counters
        int charsCount = 0;
        int wordsCount = 0;
        int linesCount = 0;

        Scanner in = null;
        File file = new File("Sample.txt");

        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))){

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                String tmpStr = scanner.nextLine();
                if (!tmpStr.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    String replaceAll = tmpStr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    charsCount += replaceAll.length();
                    wordsCount += tmpStr.split("\\s+").length;
                }
                ++linesCount;
            }

        System.out.println("# of chars: " + charsCount);
        System.out.println("# of words: " + wordsCount);
        System.out.println("# of lines: " + linesCount);
        System.out.println("# of bytes: " + file.length());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add every word in a `Set`, and get its size ?

Comment: @user7294900 but by using boolean containsValue(Object value) method or boolean containsKey(Object key)?

Comment: @Asew so I dont have to check if there already is a word like this? I know that Set has no duplicates, but simply executing add() method will add a char there if there is no such a word already and won't do so if there is?

Comment: You should add every word to the set, not every character. Trying to add a word that is already there won’t do anything.

Comment: Didn't  `wordsCount += tmpStr.trim().split("\\s+").length;` work?

Comment: Use a set container

Comment: @JeyKey You, indeed, dont need to check if the word is already here with a `Set`, as the `add()` method simply wont add an existing word.

Answer (score 0):

To get unique words and their counts:
1. Split your obtained line from file into a string array
2. Store the contents of this string array in a Hashset
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 till end of file
4. Get unique words and their count from the Hashset

I prefer posting logic and pseudo code as it will help OP to learn something by solving posted problem.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how my code works:

File with words "aa bb cc cc aa aa" has 3 unique words.

First, turn words into a string with each word separated by "-".

- **String: "aa-bb-cc-cc-aa-aa-"**
- Get the first word: "aa", set the UniqueWordCount = 1, and then replace "aa-" with "".
- **New String: "bb-cc-cc-"**
- Get the first word: "bb", set the UniqueWordCount = 2, and then replace "bb-" with "".
- **New String: "cc-cc-"**
- Get the first word: "cc", set the UniqueWordCount = 3, and then replace "cc-" with "".
- **New String: ""**, you stop when the string is empty.

```
private static int getUniqueWordCountInFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        String fileWordsAsString = getFileWords(file);
        int uniqueWordCount = 0; 
        
        int i = 0; 
        while (!(fileWordsAsString.isEmpty()) && !(fileWordsAsString.isBlank())) {
            
            if (Character.toString(fileWordsAsString.charAt(i)).equals(" ")) {
                fileWordsAsString = fileWordsAsString.replaceAll(fileWordsAsString.substring(0, i+1),""); 
                i = 0;
                uniqueWordCount++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        return uniqueWordCount;
        
    }
    
    private static String getFileWords(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
         
        String toReturn = "";
        
        try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
                if (fileReader.hasNextInt()) {
                    fileReader.nextInt();
                } else {
                    toReturn += fileReader.next() + " ";
                }
            }
        }
        
        return toReturn;
    }
```

If you want to use my code just pass getUniqueWordCountInFile() the file that has the words for which you want to count the unique words.

Answer (score -3):

hey @JeyKey you can use HashMap. Here I using Iterator too. You can check out this code.

```
    public class CountUniqueWords {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException { 

    File f = new File("File Name");
    ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
    HashMap<String, Integer> listOfWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
    int i=0;
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
    String s=in.next();
    //System.out.println(s);
    arr.add(s);
    }
    Iterator itr=arr.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {i++;

        listOfWords.put((String) itr.next(), i);
        //System.out.println(listOfWords);    //for Printing the words 
     }

    Set<Object> uniqueValues = new HashSet<Object>(listOfWords.values()); 

    System.out.println("The number of unique words: "+uniqueValues.size());
    }
    }
```

Comment: So you used ArrayList to store words... just to iterate over it and put it in the map (named `listOfWords` to add to confusion)? And you use the map just to use it's values in a Set? Why?