# Counting the distinct words

Tags: java, algorithm, bufferedreader, treeset

how could I count the distinct words in a text that spans several lines?

> Input data:
>   You will read the text of the email from the keyboard. It can span multiple lines and contains only lowercase letters of the English alphabet and spaces.
>
> Output data:
>   A single integer representing the number of distinct words in the email will be displayed.

I have this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
    int count = 0;
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            words.add(line);
            count++;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(count);
 }
```

Basically it only works on a test, but on the rest yes it is wrong, since I understand it is because it still reads an empty space, what could I repair?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150173/how-to-count-unique-words-in-a-text-file

Comment: You are adding the entire line in `words.add(line);` instead of words.

Comment: No need in `catch {}` block here, exceptions thrown from main method are printed anyway. Also sorted set is unnecessary here, I'd used HashSet instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
words.add(line);
```

to add the words from each `line`. Split on white space, and add the resulting tokens. Like,

```
words.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s+")));
```

And then change

```
System.out.println(count);
```

to

```
System.out.println(words.size());
```

Finally, eliminate `count` (you don't need it, and the `Set` "counts" the elements by the number of elements with-in the set; i.e. `words.size()`). And, unless there's some reason to order your elements, use a `HashSet`.

```
Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
```

Should be (as far as I can tell)

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Did you `import java.util.Arrays;` - the code is correct, do you have some other requirements you have not shared? Have you followed all of this answer?

Comment: I tested the result on ideone.com and yes, but I do not know why I take 0 points now.

Comment: Ok, I dropped - 1 from the final result and received 100 points, do you know why?